# Putting number of rows in section title

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would need to include the number of rows in the section title, like TODAY (6), that means that on section titled TODAY there are 6 rows (core data objects in my case). I know that it is to find here:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
```

But I don't know how to include this on each section to be shown as a label text.
Any advice is welcome....

```
#import "ToDoItemsTableViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"
#import "ToDoSubItemsTableViewController.h"

@interface ToDoItemsTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation ToDoItemsTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    return [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]managedObjectContext];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
        abort();
    }
}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"addToDoItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        AddToDoItemViewController *addToDoItemViewController = (AddToDoItemViewController*)navigationController.topViewController;
        ToDoItem *addToDoItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        addToDoItemViewController.addToDoItem = addToDoItem;
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toToDoSubItems"]){

        ToDoSubItemsTableViewController *todoSubItemsTableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ToDoItem *selectedToDoItem = (ToDoItem*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        todoSubItemsTableViewController.selectedToDoItem = selectedToDoItem;



    }




}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    ToDoItem *todoItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = todoItem.todoName;



    NSDate *fechaToDO = todoItem.todoDueDate;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
    NSString *fechaToDo = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fechaToDO];



    cell.detailTextLabel.text = fechaToDo;
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *header = @"customHeader";

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *vHeader;

    vHeader = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:header];

    if (!vHeader) {
        vHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:header];
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    if (section == 1) {
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else {
        [vHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    vHeader.textLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    return vHeader;
}
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{




    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    NSString *sectionname = [theSection name];

    if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        return @"Overdue";

    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        return @"Today";
    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"2"]){
        return @"Upcoming";
    }




    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count]>0){
        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }

}


#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Section

-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController{

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil){
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoDueDate" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"todoName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1, nil];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}


#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Delegates

-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}

-(void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:{

            ToDoItem *changeToDoItem = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.textLabel.text = changeToDoItem.todoName;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = changeToDoItem.todoDescription;
        }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }


}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type{

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }

}





/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        ToDoItem *ToDoItemToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [context deleteObject:ToDoItemToDelete];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        }

    }
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today(%d)", [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
    section]];
```

Comment: Query the table view directly instead, [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]

Comment: @SomeGuy Yea, I don't know what I was thinking.  Forgot could just call `numberOfRowsInSection` on a `UITableView`, but shouldn't use `self.tableView` since this is most likely being called in a data source method that is sending the `tableView` as one of the arguments.